# How to verify a JWT on a workstation using .NET

Tags: .net, jwt

Is it possible for a desktop application verify that a JWT is valid and do so using .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.

Install the nuget package
PM> Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

and then you can use the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class like this

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
handler.ValidateToken(tokenString, param, out validatedToken);
```